# FTL Firing weapons during stealth warmup period

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

In FTL, when you activate your stealth, there is a very small window where the stealth is taking effect.

Will firing your weapons during this period contribute to the shortened duration that firing weapons during stealth causes?

Comment: why don't you shoot during this period and then count out the rest of your stealth.

Comment: @I am unable to for awhile, and even if I was, it's completely random whether or not I'll be able to get the stealth upgrade.

Comment: @Ataxia Not if you use one of the stealth ships...

Comment: @Psychemaster Of which I do not have unlocked.

Comment: of course it will be shortened, by how many secs, i don't know. but you can buy the stealth weapons augmentation so firing weapons while in stealth will not shorten the time of stealth.

Comment: @ken that was not the question.  I am aware that firing your weapons while in stealth will damage the duration of my stealth.  I don't know if it will during the small warmup period.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just tested this with the Stealth cruiser. On the first node I jumped to, I tested the following five times each:

- Pausing, activating cloak, resuming, waiting 1 second, and then firing Dual Lasers
- Pausing, activating cloak and firing Dual Lasers at the same time, resuming
- Pausing, activating cloak, resuming and pausing before the cloak visualization has taken full effect, firing Dual Lasers, resuming

In all cases, the total cloak time visibly dropped by a bar once the weapon was fired.

I concluded that the game engine considers you to be cloaked from the moment the system is activated, and therefore that your weapons will affect the total cloak time whenever you activate them in that period (unless, of course, you have the Stealth Weapons upgrade.)

It is also worth noting that if you fire your weapons *just before* activating your cloak, you don't lose any time (even if the weapon is a burst weapon and is technically firing *during* the cloak charge, as long as the initial shot was launched prior to the cloak.)